# SCRIPT5022: Sys.ArgumentException:

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, scriptresource.axd

I am facing a strange issue. I have a site which is working fine when opening in IE10 Win7 on my local + one production Server, but not when browse from my Main Production server.
Giving Error

```
SCRIPT5022: Sys.ArgumentException: Value must not be null for Controls and Behaviors.
Parameter name: element  ScriptResource.axd, line 4622 character 23
```

and here is the code in `scriptResource` that is cosing this

```
  if (e) throw e;
if (type.inheritsFrom(Sys.UI.Behavior) || type.inheritsFrom(Sys.UI.Control)) {
    if (!element) throw Error.argument('element', Sys.Res.createNoDom);

// Name:        MicrosoftAjax.debug.js
// Assembly:    AjaxControlToolkit
// Version:     4.1.7.123
// FileVersion: 4.1.7.0123
// (c) 2010 CodePlex Foundation
```

This is only happening in case of IE10 and works fine on all browsers. Another things that i have noted is that when i run the same page with IE10 "Compatibility View" than it works.

Can any body help me out what i am missing? I have tried some solutions available on the internet but to no effect.

Comment: i am also getting same issue
"SCRIPT5022: Sys.ArgumentException: Value must not be null for Controls and Behaviors.
Parameter name: element" in IE11
Can  any one help me??